# Does Bigquery support triggers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are currently using AWS RDS as our databases. In tables, we defined some insert or update triggers on tables. I would like to know if Bigquery also support triggers?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BigQuery is a data warehouse product, similar to AWS Redshift and AWS Athena and there is no trigger support.

If you used AWS RDS so far, you need to check [Google CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/).

> Google Cloud SQL is an easy-to-use service that delivers fully managed
>   SQL databases in the cloud. Google Cloud SQL provides either MySQL or
>   PostgreSQL databases.

If you have a heavy load, then check out [Google Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/) it's even better for full scalable relational db.

> Cloud Spanner is the only enterprise-grade, globally-distributed, and
>   strongly consistent database service built for the cloud specifically
>   to combine the benefits of relational database structure with
>   non-relational horizontal scale.

Answer (score 2):

Big Query doesn't have the feature as stated by the colleague above.
However it has an event api based on it's audit logs. You can inspect it and trigger events with cloud functions as per:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events

Regards

Answer (score -2):

You can use Google Clod run for any event triggers in Big query. This is based on logs written for each record.

Reference :- https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events