# How do you set up a trigger with SQL queries in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, triggers, google-bigquery

I am trying to see if I can set up a trigger system, so whenever a new row of data is populated in these tables A, B, and C --> it populates new rows into a new table I created (table D, for example)?

I'm using Bigquery. Does this platform allow this capability?

Not sure what kind of coding should be used for this...(Insert into, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late to the party, but this is possible now. https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events

Comment: Late is better than never. The future is now...is now...is now. Unrelated but for people using Spanner to BigQuery this solves the trigger issue for Spanner too.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are not supported on BigQuery, basically because they are not aligned to the intended use patterns of the product. You may also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993415/does-bigquery-support-triggers) existing question.

There is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115569337) in place for an interesting approach to trigger an action when rows are loaded to BigQuery, but currently there is no ETA for it.

You my want to consider [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) as different alternative, instead of using triggers, you may orchestrate your data ingestion tasks.

Answer (score -1):

BigQuery is a data warehouse, and there is no trigger support.

Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/sql/ , maybe it will help you.